# how to save a textarea contents of an html5 form to a text file at server side using php?

Tags: php, html

how to save a textarea contents of an html5 form to a text file at server side?
e.g.

```
<form>
     <textarea name="content ">
            contents...
      </textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: if above is the form i want to store the user input info.

Comment: please, show how you tried to handle this form on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out... this code will save the data to text file...

**EDIT** : put below code in your form action page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file = 'your_path/filename.txt';
    if(file_exist($file))
    {
      file_put_contents($file,$_POST['content']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help you.. In the array, instead of giving the values manually, take them from the form and post them in the array... These values will be stored in the text file..

```
<?php
    $file=fopen("user.txt","a+");
    $details=array('FirstName'=>'Johny',
                    'LastName'=>'Bravo',
                    'Gender'=>'Male');
    foreach($details as $column=>$data)
    {   
$info=$column."::".$data." ";
        if(fwrite($file,$info))
        {
            echo $column."::".$data." Inserted into File <br />";
        }
    }
?>
```